# Issue while connecting to a server via TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcp, teamspeak

I'm testing a application where I connect to a server with a TcpClient, sending strings and waiting for a response. This works when stepping through the app but when running it without breakpoints, the result is empty.

To be specific: I want to contact a TS3 server.
Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var response = new ServerConnection().GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("Response erhalten!");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ServerConnection
{
    public string GetResponse()
    {
        string result = "";
        using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("193.111.136.17"), 10011);
            using (var ns = client.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] bytesToSend;
                bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("help");
                ns.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                byte[] response = new byte[1024];
                if (ns.DataAvailable)
                    ns.Read(response, 0, response.Length);

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(response))
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me, WHY THE HELL the reponse is filled with `\0` when running it normally (resulting in blank text for `result`), but containing some "usefull" text when stepping through this? This drives me crazy... aaarg!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you only stopping to check at `result = sr.ReadToEnd();` and if not, could it be you aren't waiting long enough for the returned response when running normally?

Comment: do you know how much time the server needs to respond between the write and read? Have you tried to make some intermediate outputs to check whether you actually ever get into the `if (ns.DataAvailable)` condition? maybe an asynch approach would be more appropriate?

Comment: I made my breakpoint on the connect() method of the client

Comment: don't set any breakpoints, try and put a `Console.WriteLine(ns.DataAvailable.ToString())` right after the line `if (ns.DataAvailable)` see whether you get true or false

Answer (score 0):

The `NetworkStream.Read` method is blocking, there's no need to check the value of the `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` property.

If your code executes "too quickly", the value of the `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` property might be `false`, therefore no data will be read from the stream.